# Session in Swift? Is it possible?

Tags: ios, swift

If session in HTML5 is `sessionStorage.userId`, how about session in swift? I don't want use CoreData.

Comment: Define session at this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Near to sessions, use app preference :

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/